# Verify token ID and access token with PHP

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, lib

How can I use the OPENID with PHP, without using libs?

I was using the Twitch OAuth2.0 and after building the authentication I get the "id_token" and an "access_token".

How do I validate the id_token and the access_token using PHP to get a code?

Answer (score 2):

**ID Token** is a kind of **JWT**. JWT is a kind of either **JWS** or **JWE**. The following are relevant specifications.

- OpenID Connect Core 1.0, [2. ID Token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)
- [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) : JSON Web Token (JWT)
- [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) : JSON Web Signature (JWS)
- [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7156) : JSON Web Encryption (JWE)

If you want to validate ID tokens without using libraries, as the first step, you have to understand the specifications. Then, do all the stuff like decoding, decrypting and verifying signatures using PHP standard functions.

NOTE: Regardless of whether ID Token is encrypted or not, a signature is attached. To verify the signature, if the algorithm of the signature is asymmetric, you have to get the public key which corresponds to the private key used for the signature.

On the other hand, the format of **access tokens** varies depending on implementations.

Comment: Can you write a example code pls? It help me to understand

Comment: Visit https://jwt.io/, and you can find JWT libraries for PHP there. Pick up one from among them and read the source code of it. The source code must be a good example.

Comment: You know some very simple library which verify the token_id

Comment: firebase/php-jwt or lcobucci/jwt

Comment: An example could be really useful, it's hard to find on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it fully answers the question.
I was looking at it a lot and could not find any quick and small code that does it.
I did not find any simple examples. So, I figured it out myself and want to share it here.

The code I will show here only uses one lib for the part generating the public key

The example can be used with Google or Microsoft.

The first part is storing your client ID, kids, and certs URLs.

```php
<?php

class AuthConstants
{
    const GOOGLE_KID = 'WRITE_HERE_THE_KID';
    const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'WRITE_HERE_YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
    const GOOGLE_CERTS_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs';
    const MICROSOFT_KID = 'WRITE_HERE_THE_KID';
    const MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID = 'WRITE_HERE_YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
    const MICROSOFT_CERTS_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys';
}
```

Some helpers:

```php
<?php
class CommonHelpers {

    public static function base64_url_decode($arg)
    {
        $res = $arg;
        $res = str_replace('-', '+', $res);
        $res = str_replace('_', '/', $res);
        switch (strlen($res) % 4) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 2:
                $res .= "==";
                break;
            case 3:
                $res .= "=";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $res = base64_decode($res);
        return $res;
    }

}
```

And the `IdToken` class with logic to verify it

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger;

class IdToken
{
    private ?string $id_token;
    public array $headers;
    public array $claims;

    public function __construct($id_token)
    {
        $this->id_token = $id_token;
    }

    public function load_and_validate(): bool
    {
        $token_arr = explode('.', $this->id_token);
        $headers_enc = $token_arr[0];
        $claims_enc = $token_arr[1];

        $this->headers = json_decode(CommonHelpers::base64_url_decode($headers_enc), TRUE);
        $this->claims = json_decode(CommonHelpers::base64_url_decode($claims_enc), TRUE);

        if (time() > $this->claims['exp'])
            return false;  // The token expired

        $certs_url = self::get_validated_certs_url();
        if (!$certs_url)
            return false;

        $public_key = self::generate_public_key($certs_url);

        $token_sig_enc = $token_arr[2];
        $signature = CommonHelpers::base64_url_decode($token_sig_enc);

        $token_valid = openssl_verify($headers_enc . '.' . $claims_enc, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        return $token_valid == 1;
    }


    function get_validated_certs_url(): ?string
    {
        $kid = $this->headers['kid'];
        if (!$kid)
            return null;

        $aud = $this->claims['aud'];
        if (!$aud)
            return null;

        if ($kid === AuthConstants::GOOGLE_KID && $aud === AuthConstants::GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
            return AuthConstants::GOOGLE_CERTS_URL;

        if ($kid === AuthConstants::MICROSOFT_KID && $aud === AuthConstants::MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID)
            return AuthConstants::MICROSOFT_CERTS_URL;

        return null;
    }


    function generate_public_key($certs_url)
    {
        $publicKeys = json_decode(file_get_contents($certs_url));

        $keyId = $this->headers['kid'];

        $publicKey = null;
        foreach ($publicKeys->keys as $key) {
            if ($key->kid == $keyId) {
                $publicKey = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$publicKey)
            return null; // Unable to find public key

        $modulus = $publicKey->n;
        $exponent = $publicKey->e;

        $key = PublicKeyLoader::load([
            'n' => new BigInteger(CommonHelpers::base64_url_decode($modulus), 256),
            'e' => new BigInteger(CommonHelpers::base64_url_decode($exponent), 256),
        ]);
        $formattedPublicKey = $key->toString('PKCS8');
        if (!is_string($formattedPublicKey)) {
            return null; // 'Failed to initialize the key'
        }

        return $formattedPublicKey;
    }


}
```

You will need to run this command in where the `IdToken.php` is located:

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0
```

To install composer, see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

To validate the id_token, call:

```php
$id_token = "eyj................" // replace this line with real id_token
$id_token = new IdToken($id_token);
$is_valid = $id_token->load_and_validate();
```